# Filtering out with conditions of descending priority

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm having trouble with selecting rows based on conditions of descending priority. I've tried finding out a solution but just can't. It seems like a simple task but I just cant figure it out.

This is just a general example of what I would like to do.

```
structure(list(type = c(100815L, 100815L, 100815L, 100815L, 
100815L, 100815L, 100815L), x = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(1.51098844290943, 2.31001922745969, 1.52639281812227, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), z = c(0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 50, 25)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


group <- group %>%
  group_by(type) %>% 
     filter(sum(x == "Yes" &
                y == min(y[x == "Yes"]) &
                z == max(z[y == min(y[x == "Yes"])])) == 1)
```

So basically I want to filter from a large sample the groups that has exactly one such case. i.e. there are no ties:

- When x = "Yes" AND

  - given that x = "Yes" choose the minimum y of those who have x = "Yes" AND

    - from this final smallest group select z that has the largest value.

Basically it's also possible that no such final value exists.

This is a simplified example of a problem I constantly run into. I have a larger dataset where I need assign values to cells based on multiple conditions that are of descending priority. I want to be able to stack conditions sequentially.

**Update**

```
structure(list(type = c(7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 
7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 
7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L
), x= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), y = c(1.66703903751618, 
0, 0.899002060282742, 1.77844476717205, 0.858205995526113, 1.77844476717205, 
0.894654725714929, 2.28497216539696, 0, 0.899002060282742, 2.28497216539696, 
2.85895315127563, 2.85895315127563, 0, 2.85895315127563, 0.858205995526113, 
0.894654725714929, 1.66703903751618, 1.66703903751618, 0, 0, 
1.66703903751618, 0.894654725714929), z = c(6.67, 
0, 3.33, 6.67, 3.33, 6.67, 2, 6.67, 3.33, 3.33, 2, 3.33, 3.33, 
2, 3.33, 6.67, 6.67, 6.67, 2, 6.67, 3.33, 6.67, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# And the code that I attempted:

test <- test %>%
          group_by(type) %>%
          arrange(type) %>%
          filter(sum(y == min(y)  & x == "Yes") == 1) %>%
          ungroup()
```

The group here should be filtered in by my understanding but just doesn't. There are two "Yes" but the other has a smaller y and there should be only one case of the rule happening, yet the filter doesn't pick it.

This was just a limited version with two conditions. Basically I am trying to assign a "Yes" to just one x. If there is more than one, the tie is broken by y. If there is still a tie, the tie is broken by z. And so on I hope. I just can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
df %>% group_by(type) %>% filter(x == "Yes",y == min(y),z == max(z))

# # A tibble: 1 × 4
# # Groups:   type [1]
#     type x         y     z
#    <int> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 100815 Yes       0    50
```

Comment: I think that is using global values for `min(y)` and `max(z)`, rather than values within the subsets.  You get the same answers with the sample data, but if no case has `x=="Yes"`, `y == 0`, and `z == 50`, you get no cases at all.  Splitting the `filter` call into three separate calls seems to do it.

Comment: I get the same answer either way, but I didn't test it on an alternative data set.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was checking if it works in all instances. Your solution helps with this particular group, but not all and I don't understand why. I'll update the post to show where that selection rule did not work.

Comment: Applying the filters simultaneously (the comma acts as equivalent to AND logic) leads to potential breakage: if the `min(y)` value occurs for `x == "No"`, the logic breaks, and no rule remains. Changing the code to three chained `filter` calls should lead to the correct behaviour.

Comment: @user2554330 splitting the `filter` worked to separate the value, but the side effect is that it separates the row from the group. I'm trying to gather the groups where the condition holds and then in the next step change x to "No" for the rows that the condition doesn't hold for. I'll update the question to show you what I'm attempting after this step.

Comment: @Moz, I think your update is a different question.  I'd remove the changes, and post them as a new question.  The old one was basically "How do I apply filters sequentially?".  The new one is "How do I use the result of sequential filters to identify larger groups?"

Comment: @user2554330, thanks I'll do that. I guess you answer solved the issue. How can I mark that you comment was the solution?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  @Kat got most of the answer; she should edit it and you should accept it.