# How do I use the result of sequential filters to identify larger groups

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

This question is continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883160/filtering-out-with-conditions-of-descending-priority).

Here is my original example code. I am attempting to first identify all the groups in my larger dataset in which there is exactly one case where x = "Yes" and y is the minimum of all x = "Yes" (there may be multiple x = "Yes" in a given group).

Ideally I'd like to find a better way to manage this for other cases as well where multiple scenarios arise that need to be treated differently.

```
structure(list(type = c(7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 
7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 
7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L, 7345L
), x= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), y = c(1.66703903751618, 
0, 0.899002060282742, 1.77844476717205, 0.858205995526113, 1.77844476717205, 
0.894654725714929, 2.28497216539696, 0, 0.899002060282742, 2.28497216539696, 
2.85895315127563, 2.85895315127563, 0, 2.85895315127563, 0.858205995526113, 
0.894654725714929, 1.66703903751618, 1.66703903751618, 0, 0, 
1.66703903751618, 0.894654725714929), z = c(6.67, 
0, 3.33, 6.67, 3.33, 6.67, 2, 6.67, 3.33, 3.33, 2, 3.33, 3.33, 
2, 3.33, 6.67, 6.67, 6.67, 2, 6.67, 3.33, 6.67, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# And the code that I attempted:

test <- test %>%
          group_by(type) %>%
          arrange(type) %>%
          filter(sum(y == min(y)  & x == "Yes") == 1) %>%
          ungroup()

    test <- test %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
      mutate(x = case_when(y == min(y)  & x == "Yes" ~ "Yes",
                           TRUE ~ "No"))
```

Basically I am trying to assign a "Yes" to just one x. If there is more than one, the tie is broken by y. If there is still a tie, the tie is broken by z. And so on, I hope. The solution to my original question helped me identify the correct row from the group, but as a side effect the row gets separated from the group. This stops me from doing the next step: assigning x = "No" to all rows where the sequential conditions/filters don't apply.

This is a part of a longer code where I'm trying to determine which is x = "Yes" for each group.The preceding step (not pasted here) gathers all the type groups where there is more than one x into the `test` (sub)dataframe.

Originally I tried making a long chain of ifelse() statements that got more specific after each fork, resulting in multiple end nodes from  where I could then assign the correct x = "Yes". i.e.

- if x = "Yes" > 1 in the group

  - y = min(y) -> x = "Yes" (end)
  - if multiple y = min(y)

    - z = max(z) -> x = "Yes" (end)
    - if multiple z = max(z)

      - etc.

Also tried solving this with case_when()'s and if()'s, but it quickly became unmanageable and didn't work.

```
test <- test %>%
          group_by(type) %>%
          arrange(type) %>%
          filter(x == "Yes") %>%
             filter(y == min(y)) %>%
               ungroup()

    test <- test %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
      mutate(x = case_when(y == min(y)  & x == "Yes" ~ "Yes",
                           TRUE ~ "No"))
```

**Update**
Here is another 4 groups

```
structure(list(type= c(104554L, 104554L, 104554L, 104554L, 
104554L, 104554L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 
104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 
104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 
104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 
104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 104421L, 102112L, 102112L, 
102112L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 
60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 60782L, 
60782L), x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), y = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2946042141164, 2.67234885411271, 1.40369726013573, 
1.98085120336689, 2.74669393960781, 0.886078834754662, 1.40369726013573, 
0, 0.678362545627373, 0, 1.66399485899006, 1.66399485899006, 
0, 1.98085120336689, 1.66399485899006, 1.2946042141164, 1.66399485899006, 
0, 0.875240408099169, 0, 1.2946042141164, 1.2946042141164, 1.2946042141164, 
1.96099458530063, 1.28997868511804, 0.886078834754662, 1.66399485899006, 
2.32273877338854, 1.66399485899006, 1.2946042141164, 0, 0, 1.28997868511804, 
0, 0.720735853734961, 1.86840611019821, 1.48552201407479, 0, 
0.970616854290719, 0.720735853734961, 0.720735853734961, 0.721774434375742, 
1.86840611019821, 0, 0.539800019998205, 0, 1.86840611019821, 
0, 1.48552201407479, 0), z = c(7.1428, 10.7142, 
25, 17.8571, 14.2857, 25, 1.6666, 3.9583, 1.25, 3.9583, 3.9583, 
3.9583, 3.9583, 3.125, 5, 0, 1.25, 3.9583, 3.125, 5, 0, 2.7083, 
3.9583, 1.25, 1.25, 5.2083, 3.9583, 5, 2.7083, 3.9583, 2.7083, 
3.9583, 5.2083, 5, 2.7083, 5, 1.25, 33.3333, 10, 25, 4.31, 4.31, 
4.31, 10.15, 4.31, 4.31, 10.15, 4.31, 4.31, 7.61, 4.31, 4.31, 
4.31, 10.15, 4.31, 10.15), a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is desired outcome:

```
# A tibble: 56 x 5
        type   x                        y                z   a
        <int> <fct>                     <dbl>          <dbl> <fct>      
 1     104554 No                        0               7.14 No         
 2     104554 No                        0              10.7  No         
 3     104554 Yes                       0              25    Yes        
 4     104554 No                        0              17.9  Yes        
 5     104554 No                        0              14.3  No         
 6     104554 No                        0              25    Yes        
 7     104421 No                        1.29            1.67 No         
 8     104421 No                        2.67            3.96 No         
 9     104421 No                        1.40            1.25 No         
10     104421 No                        1.98            3.96 No         
11     104421 No                        2.75            3.96 No         
12     104421 No                        0.886           3.96 No         
13     104421 No                        1.40            3.96 No         
14     104421 No                        0               3.12 Yes        
15     104421 No                        0.678           5    No         
16     104421 No                        0               0    Yes        
17     104421 No                        1.66            1.25 No         
18     104421 No                        1.66            3.96 No         
19     104421 No                        0               3.12 Yes        
20     104421 No                        1.98            5    No         
21     104421 No                        1.66            0    Yes        
22     104421 No                        1.29            2.71 No         
23     104421 No                        1.66            3.96 No         
24     104421 No                        0               1.25 No         
25     104421 No                        0.875           1.25 No         
26     104421 Yes                       0               5.21 Yes        
27     104421 No                        1.29            3.96 No         
28     104421 No                        1.29            5    No         
29     104421 No                        1.29            2.71 No         
30     104421 No                        1.96            3.96 No         
31     104421 No                        1.29            2.71 No         
32     104421 No                        0.886           3.96 No         
33     104421 No                        1.66            5.21 Yes        
34     104421 No                        2.32            5    No         
35     104421 No                        1.66            2.71 No         
36     104421 No                        1.29            5    No         
37     104421 No                        0               1.25 No         
38     102112 Yes                       0              33.3  Yes        
39     102112 No                        1.29           10    No         
40     102112 No                        0              25    Yes        
41      60782 No                        0.721           4.31 No         
42      60782 No                        1.87            4.31 No         
43      60782 No                        1.49            4.31 No         
44      60782 Yes                       0              10.2  Yes        
45      60782 No                        0.971           4.31 No         
46      60782 No                        0.721           4.31 No         
47      60782 No                        0.721          10.2  Yes        
48      60782 No                        0.722           4.31 No         
49      60782 No                        1.87            4.31 No         
50      60782 No                        0               7.61 Yes        
51      60782 No                        0.540           4.31 Yes        
52      60782 No                        0               4.31 No         
53      60782 No                        1.87            4.31 No         
54      60782 Yes                       0              10.2  Yes        
55      60782 No                        1.49            4.31 No         
56      60782 Yes                       0              10.2  Yes
```

The last group results in 3 rows tied. I didn't notice it when I picked the groups. However, these cases where a single x = Yes cannot be determined happens in the actual data. There are over 10 000 groups and in the end some will need to be manually determined.

On a general level I'd like to find a smarter way to edit data when it has these kinds of requirements, i.e. the structure I tried to illustrate with the bullet points above. I think this is useful in general and not just specific to this particular data.

Comment: Please make a better example containing data that are tied for `x == "Yes"` and other cases you want to handle. At the moment it's hard to test any code on your dataset since filtering for `x == "Yes"` and for "y == min(y)" only gives one result.

Comment: Please also make sure to add to your question what the final result should look like for your modified example. If the code does what it should, what is the final outcome?

Comment: How many conditions so you want to use? I think you have to write a custom function for this special problem.

Comment: (1) Why is no 47 resulting in "Yes"? (2) Why is no 40 "Yes"? (3) Your `structure` output doesn't match the shown tibble...

Comment: The shown tibble was what I'm attempting to get, not what the structure gives. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the `structure` (beginner), but it does give me the original correct dataframe when I use it again. Group 60782 of `type`  has initially six rows with `x` = Yes. The minimum `y` among those six rows is 0, which eliminates rows 47 and 51 because they have `y` of 0.7207 and 0.5398 respectively. The four remaining rows are then evaluated based on `z`. The maximum among the four remaining is 10.15, which eliminates row 50 because it has `z` = 7.61. Do you understand what I mean now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to build groups based on your conditions. If `x == "Yes"` returns only one element, this element satisfies the `min(y)` and `max(z)` condition for this subset. Therefore you can apply all conditions and don't need to use several cases:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

test %>%
  group_by(type, x_yes = x == "Yes") %>%
  mutate(y_min = min(y) == y) %>%
  group_by(y_min, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(z_max = max(z) == z) %>%
  group_by(z_max, .add = TRUE) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map_df(~ .x %>%
           add_count() %>% 
           mutate(outcome = ifelse(
             all(x_yes, y_min, z_max, n == 1),
             "Yes",
             "No")
             )
         )
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 56 x 10
     type x         y     z a     x_yes y_min z_max     n outcome
    <int> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <int> <chr>  
 1  60782 No    0.721  4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 2  60782 No    1.87   4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 3  60782 No    1.49   4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 4  60782 No    0.971  4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 5  60782 No    0.721  4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 6  60782 No    0.722  4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 7  60782 No    1.87   4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 8  60782 No    1.87   4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
 9  60782 No    1.49   4.31 No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      9 No     
10  60782 No    0      4.31 No    FALSE TRUE  TRUE      1 No     
11  60782 Yes   0.540  4.31 Yes   TRUE  FALSE FALSE     1 No     
12  60782 Yes   0.721 10.2  Yes   TRUE  FALSE TRUE      1 No     
13  60782 Yes   0      7.61 Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     1 No     
14  60782 Yes   0     10.2  Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      3 No     
15  60782 Yes   0     10.2  Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      3 No     
16  60782 Yes   0     10.2  Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      3 No     
17 102112 No    1.29  10    No    FALSE TRUE  TRUE      1 No     
18 102112 Yes   0     25    Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     1 No     
19 102112 Yes   0     33.3  Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      1 Yes    
20 104421 No    1.29   1.67 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
21 104421 No    2.67   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
22 104421 No    1.40   1.25 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
23 104421 No    1.98   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
24 104421 No    2.75   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
25 104421 No    0.886  3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
26 104421 No    1.40   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
27 104421 No    1.66   1.25 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
28 104421 No    1.66   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
29 104421 No    1.29   2.71 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
30 104421 No    1.66   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
31 104421 No    0.875  1.25 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
32 104421 No    1.29   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
33 104421 No    1.29   2.71 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
34 104421 No    1.96   3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
35 104421 No    1.29   2.71 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
36 104421 No    0.886  3.96 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
37 104421 No    1.66   2.71 No    FALSE FALSE FALSE    18 No     
38 104421 No    0.678  5    No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      5 No     
39 104421 No    1.98   5    No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      5 No     
40 104421 No    1.29   5    No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      5 No     
41 104421 No    2.32   5    No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      5 No     
42 104421 No    1.29   5    No    FALSE FALSE TRUE      5 No     
43 104421 No    0      1.25 No    FALSE TRUE  TRUE      2 No     
44 104421 No    0      1.25 No    FALSE TRUE  TRUE      2 No     
45 104421 Yes   1.66   0    Yes   TRUE  FALSE FALSE     1 No     
46 104421 Yes   1.66   5.21 Yes   TRUE  FALSE TRUE      1 No     
47 104421 Yes   0      3.12 Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
48 104421 Yes   0      0    Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
49 104421 Yes   0      3.12 Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
50 104421 Yes   0      5.21 Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      1 Yes    
51 104554 No    0      7.14 No    FALSE TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
52 104554 No    0     10.7  No    FALSE TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
53 104554 No    0     14.3  No    FALSE TRUE  FALSE     3 No     
54 104554 No    0     25    Yes   FALSE TRUE  TRUE      1 No     
55 104554 Yes   0     17.9  Yes   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     1 No     
56 104554 Yes   0     25    Yes   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      1 Yes
```

If for a given type `x == "Yes"` and `y == min(y)` for this subgroup and `z == max(z)` for this sub-subgroup and there is only one element in the resulting group, the outcome is `"Yes"`, else it's `"No"`.

This isn't identical to your desired output, I think there are some issues regarding the actual conditions, but I think you could solve them using a similar approach.

Comment: Yes with this it can be solved. I just need to do it in a few steps. i.e. first filter groups with  `all(x_yes, n == 1)`, then  `all(x_yes, y_min, n == 1)`, then `all(x_yes, y_min, z_max, n == 1)` and so on if I have more conditions. When I get through to the last condition and there still is more than 1 that fulfills the conditions, those can be evaluated manually or left as a tie. Finally the `x` can be changed to yes or no based on the `outcome` column. Thank you!